# AJAX Servlet call Illegal State Exception

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am calling servlet with ajax and getting following exception when i deploy it to websphere. However it is working on my local machine. And as far as i understand from this [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) the reason is because i am trying to access both `response.getWriter()` and `response.getOutputStream()` method but that is not the case because i only have `getWriter` method in my code.

I've already searched for previous questions on stackoverflow but it didnt help.

So any help would be appreciated

My Servlet Code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] userStates = request.getParameterValues("user");
    String r_object_id = request.getParameter("queueId");

    boolean isUpdateSuccessfull =false;
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     

    //ArrayList
    //string[0] -> skill_id 
    //string[1] -> r_object_id
    //string[2] -> original_value

    ArrayList<String[]> updateList = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < userStates.length; i++) {

        String[] update = userStates[i].split("_");     
        updateList.add(update);
    }

    try{
         DefineSkillSet dss = new DefineSkillSet();          
         HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> userSkillMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

         for(String[] status: updateList){

             if(status == null && status.length != 2){
                 // TODO error logging 
                 HlkUtils.printErr(null, "skillSetName()", "status dizisinin boyutu yanlış");
                 continue;
             }
             // get array values
             String skillId = status[0];
             String objectId = status[1];

             // check if object ID exists in hash map
             if(!userSkillMap.containsKey(objectId)){

                 ArrayList<String> skillList = new ArrayList<String>();

                 skillList.add(skillId);

                 userSkillMap.put(objectId, skillList);
             }
             else{

                 userSkillMap.get(objectId).add(skillId);
             }
         }

         isUpdateSuccessfull = dss.Update(userSkillMap, r_object_id);


    }
    catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(isUpdateSuccessfull){
        response.getWriter().write("Güncelleme Başarılı");
    }
    else{
        response.getWriter().write("Güncelleme Yapılamadı!");
    }
}
```

My error log

```
[4/20/15 9:41:27:795 EEST] 00000128 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[dispatcherServlet]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward. Response already committed.
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1148)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.java:120)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.__AW_service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at com.emc.xcp.rest.security.filter.BasicAuthFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthFilter.java:51)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at com.emc.xcp.rest.security.filter.CSRFTokenFilter.doFilter(CSRFTokenFilter.java:23)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.__AW_doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.__AW_doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.emc.xcp.rest.security.filter.RepositoryInfoFilter.doFilter(RepositoryInfoFilter.java:33)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.emc.xcp.ui.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:26)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at com.emc.xcp.ui.web.filter.CustomCharEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomCharEncodingFilter.java:47)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:975)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)

[4/20/15 9:41:27:811 EEST] 00000128 srt           W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setStatus WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.

[4/20/15 9:41:27:811 EEST] 00000128 srt           W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse addHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

**EDIT**

As it turned out that i have a problem with servlet mapping. error log says

```
Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/UpdateSkillSet, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[com.hlk.katip.skillset.UpdateSkillSet:[/UpdateSkillSet]], application-->Katip_BPM.
```

On my local machine my url is - http://localhost:8080/KatipSkillSetWeb/skillset.jsp

And my servlet mapping is

```
 <servlet>        
    <servlet-name>UpdateSkillSet</servlet-name>       
    <servlet-class>com.hlk.katip.web.skillset.UpdateSkillSet</servlet-class>    
 </servlet>    
 <servlet-mapping>      
   <servlet-name>UpdateSkillSet</servlet-name> 
   <url-pattern>/UpdateSkillSet</url-pattern>    
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Now my url on server is - http://gtdctmdapp01:9084/Katip_BPM/skillset/skillset.jsp

And again my servlet mapping is

```
<servlet>        
    <servlet-name>UpdateSkillSet</servlet-name>       
    <servlet-class>com.hlk.katip.web.skillset.UpdateSkillSet</servlet-class>    
 </servlet>    
 <servlet-mapping>      
   <servlet-name>UpdateSkillSet</servlet-name> 
   <url-pattern>/UpdateSkillSet</url-pattern>    
 </servlet-mapping>
```

So probably on server my url-pattern should be /skillset/UpdateSkillSet

Answer (score 1):

> er.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet
>   Error]-[dispatcherServlet]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   forward. Response already committed.

The error is obvious. You have written your output to the response stream and a filter somewhere is trying to forward the request to another resource.

The first instance of a custom class that I can see in the stack trace is the following

> com.emc.xcp.rest.security.filter.BasicAuthFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthFilter.java:5‌​1)

If that is not your class, you use a framework that uses that filter class which is where you should start debugging.

Comment: I understand and will be looking at it. But what about that servlet mapping error. Did you see my edit? @ramp

Comment: Yes, the url-pattern should be /skillset/UpdateSkillSet on your server. Better to keep it consistent and change your local too accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some error is occurred in your code which is catched in try-catch block where you have written e.printStackTrace() so it will write to output stream. After caching it you are writing some content with getWriter.

Comment: What is the class name of your servlet ? Do you also have filters within your application? What is at line 51 in com.emc.xcp.rest.security.filter.BasicAuthFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthFilter.java:51) ?

Comment: My servlets classname is UpdateSkillSet. I am using my application in another platform inside an iframe. That filter you ask has nothing to do with my app. @ramp